# Web Api Visual captcha

Tags: session, asp.net-web-api, captcha

I want to implement [VisualCaptha](https://visualcaptcha.net/) in asp web api but all the examples include the use of storing the captcha object and the session variables at the time of loading. They also include getting that session object in post back but in web api there is no session So any other way to implement captcha without storing the captcha information in session variable.

PS: I want to implement only image/Visual Captcha

Any help is highly appreciated.